# different height divs float in two columns

Tags: html, css

I have two columns and want to stack divs of different heights in order of appearance.

The divs are dynamically created.

If i only float them on 50% of width, soon I come in situation that div #4 is 5 times higher than incoming few divs. Then next div is top aligned with bottom of previous div.

I need to fit child divs in container to be exact match like this:

```
----- -------
  1      2
-----
  3   -------
-----    4
  5
-----
  6
-----
  7   -------
-----    8
  9

----- 
 10   -------
        11
      -------
      -------
-----
```

Here is code snippet what I have done:

```
<style>
    .box {background:#20abff; color:#fff; width:50%; margin: 5px;}
    .left {float:left;}
    .right {float:right;}
    .container {width:205px;}
</style>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="box left" style="height:60px;">1</div>
            <div class="box left" style="height:80px;">2</div>
            <div class="box left" style="height:30px;">3</div>
            <div class="box left" style="height:70px;">4</div>
            <div class="box left" style="height:60px;">5</div>
            <div class="box left" style="height:20px;">6</div>
            <div class="box left" style="height:40px;">7</div>
            <div class="box left" style="height:90px;">8</div>
            <div class="box left" style="height:30px;">9</div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

and it looks similar to this

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/142343/divstack.html

appreciate help

Comment: Can you post your current html and css?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I see what you are trying to do.. what is the problem though?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're going to have to do this with JavaScript. If you're using jQuery, there is an excellent plugin called [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). There is also the [non jQuery version](http://vanilla-masonry.desandro.com/).

To quote the [README on GitHub](https://github.com/desandro/masonry):

> Masonry is a dynamic grid layout script. Think of it as the flip-side
>   of CSS floats. Whereas floating arranges elements horizontally then
>   vertically, Masonry arranges elements vertically, positioning each
>   element in the next open spot in the grid. The result minimizes
>   vertical gaps between elements of varying height, just like a mason
>   fitting stones in a wall.

The [single column layout](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/basic-single-column.html) is probably what you're looking for.

---

If you don't mind leaving older browsers in the dust, there are the [CSS3 `column` properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-css3-multicol-20010118/). There's an example [here, on Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html), and some documentation on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS3_Columns).

Comment: @Rama Did you even try it in IE? [The demo site](http://masonry.desandro.com/) works perfectly in IE10, 8 and 7.

Comment: Ya i tried several times. IE failed to display in masonry fashion. Where as chrome and mozilla does

Comment: Which IE did you try? Masonry works fine for me in all versions.

Comment: I am using IE 8. I want to show the webpage but cant post here.

Comment: Then create a self-contained demo in a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) and post it in a question of your own.

Comment: @JamWaffles Please check this link i have added a screen shot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950001/why-my-site-lost-its-grid-layout-alignment-its-made-with-masonry

Comment: The page loads in masonry structure upon refreshing some number of times. It is not loading at first instance in IE8

Comment: _Stop asking for help in this comment thread_. **That's what your question is for.**

Comment: Can this be solved via flex now somehow? With dynamic heights and columns set to 2 for example?

Answer (score 2):

Use 2 div as container, put both column in this container div,so give this div float left and right....it may work...
Also grid layout will work.