# Vertical top align 2 column divs of different height with float:left

Tags: html, css, css-float

The problem is that i have a form with different fields of different sizes. Each field is inside a div with float:left. And they distribute automaticlly in 2 columns. If they are all of the same height there is no problem but if not it happens the following:

[image: float:left problem]

The divs are selected in blue. I need that the last div for example goes up because if not i have a dead space there and in many other forms of my site. They are dinamic forms so i cant solve it manually. The placement must be automatic. I searched in Stack Overflow and in the internet but i couldnt find any solution.

Here is the **Divs CSS**

```
#popup #form .left{
    float:left;
    margin-left:25px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

And the **General CSS**

```
#popup{
    width:645px;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#e3e3e3;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border-color:#afafaf;
    padding:15px;
    color:#4d4d4d;
}

#popup #titulo{
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    border-bottom-color:#afafaf;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}

#popup #form #input{
    display:block;
    width:289px;
    margin-top:10px;
}

#popup #form .left{
    float:left;
    margin-left:25px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}

#popup #form .right{
    float:right;
    margin-right:25px;

}

#popup #form #input label{
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#popup #form #input input[type='text'], #popup #form #input select, #popup #form #input textarea{
    font-size:12px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#afafaf;
    width:280px;
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
}

#popup #form #input #foto{
    width:191px;
    height:87px;
    background-image:url(images/img_background.png);
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#afafaf;
    border-radius:5px;
}

#popup #form input[type='button']{
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:5px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#afafaf;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#4d4d4d;

    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 1px 1px 1px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:         inset 1px 1px 1px #ffffff;
}

#popup #form #input input[type='button']{
    width:82px;
    height:17px;
    margin-left:4px;
    line-height:14px;
}

#popup #form #submit_buttons{
    text-align:right;
    border-top-style:solid;
    border-top-width:1px;
    border-top-color:#afafaf;
    padding-top:10px;
    margin-top:15px;
}

#popup #form #submit_buttons input[type='button']{
    width:82px;
    height:30px;
}

#popup #form input[type='button']:hover{
    background-color:#cccccc;
    cursor:pointer;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

#popup #form #input table{
    width:284px;
    margin-top:2px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

#popup #form #input table tr{
    text-align:right;
    vertical-align:top;
}

#datepicker{
    background-image:url(images/datepicker.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right;
}

#popup #form #input textarea{
    height:115px;
    max-height:115px;
    min-height:115px;
    width:275px;
    max-width:275px;
    min-width:275px;
}
```

Comment: You're going to need 2 columns. Are you willing to use javascript to place them into the correct column?

Comment: They are dynamic forms so the best thing is that they place themselves automaticlly. I know how to solve it with javascript or php but i have to calculate the height of each div/input with a 2 column layout and do some math to know where to place each. If i can solve it with simple css will be the ideal thing.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you'd need to do math. You just need to iterate each section and place it in alternating columns. If you're worried about one column getting too big, then that's a more complex problem. If you're hoping css will magically solve that for you... it won't.

Comment: I think not, but it would be great. I home some day css could solve this kind of things. It will be ideal. And yes, i have to do math because i have divs/inputs of diferent height sizes. Imagine that 3 simple small inputs are in the left and other three gigant inputs in the right, it will be horrible.

Comment: Also i hope that there is a plugin somewhere that does this or something similar. If there is not i will se if i can do it to share it to the world. Surely im not the only one that has a headache with this.

Comment: Check this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11414674/different-height-divs-float-in-two-columns

Answer (score 2):

I'm providing a simplified version of the problem, but is simple enough to carry on to your example. You just need to alternate the float between left and right so they don't break :)

HTML Code:

```
<div class="box boxSize1"></div>
<div class="box boxSize1"></div>
<div class="box boxSize1"></div>
<div class="box boxSize2"></div>
<div class="box boxSize3"></div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.box {float:left; width:48%; height:40px; background:red; margin:0 1% 2%;}
.box:nth-child(even){float:right;}
.boxSize2 {height:80px; background:green;}
.boxSize3 {height:120px; background:blue;}
```

Live example:
http://jsfiddle.net/h4kE8/

Answer (score 0):

I would try throwing a `position:relative;` in with those two DIVs.  I've found that any sort of positioning problem can usually be fixed by setting a clear position attribute.

Also helps when using `position:absolute;` to have it's parent's position set.  If that doesn't work, don't underestimate tables.  People might not like them much, but if you know how to use them, they work well for stuff like this.

Lengthy, but the best advice I can give.

Answer (score 0):

The Multi-column Layout module spec has been around for a long time, but browsers have been slow to implement, so IE is almost definitely out (though there may be a polyfill that will help it limp along).

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html

http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto28/css/multicolumnlayout/

Note that this will change the order that your elements display, but it will eliminate the gap.

Answer (score 0):

I would in your case have the id, nombre and descripcion sit in the same div, call it left div. Then have the rest of the content on the right sit on another div call it right div and have them both float left. as follows

**css**

```
.left { 
  float:left;
}
.right {
 float:left;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="left">
/*id, nombre and descripcion */
</div>

<div id="right">
/* the rest */
</div>
```