# Create layout HTML with different div with different height

Tags: html, css, layout

I would like to create a layout with divs with different height.

Example image: 
[image]

I would like even that div can change the height based on the content.

In my code, I put a fixed height for the div so I want to modify it but I don't know how.

This is my code:

HTML

```
<div>
    <div class="g-block-1">
        <div class="block1"></div> <div class="block2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="g-block-2">
        <div class="block3"></div> 
        <div class="block4"></div>
        <div class="block5"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.block1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: red;
}

.block2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.block3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.block4{
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    color: black;
}

.block5 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    color: pink;
}

.g-block-1 {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.g-block-2 {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [different height divs float in two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11414674/different-height-divs-float-in-two-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?
 https://jsfiddle.net/scorpio777/wwwLmvfu/

```
<style>
pre {margin:0 padding:0;}
.block1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border:1px solid;
    border-color:red;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.block2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border:1px solid;
    border-color:orange;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.block3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border:1px solid;
    border-color:blue;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.block4{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border:1px solid;
    border-color:green;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.block5 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border:1px solid;
    border-color:pink;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.g-block-1 {
    width: 50%;
    height:100%;
    float: left;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.g-block-2 {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
}
</style>
<div>
    <div class="g-block-1">
        <div class="block1">
          <pre>
              some content
              some content
              some content
              some content
              some content
              some content
              some content
              some content
          </pre>
        </div> 
        <div class="block2">
          <pre>
              some content
              some content
              some content
              some content
              some content
              some content
              some content
              some content
              some content
              some content
          </pre>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="g-block-2">
        <div class="block3">
          <pre>
              some content
              some content
              some content
              some content
              some content
          </pre>
        </div> 
        <div class="block4">
          <pre>
              some content
              some content
              some content
              some content
              some content
          </pre>
        </div>
        <div class="block5">
          <pre>
              some content
              some content
              some content
              some content
              some content
          </pre>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this *responsive* solution:

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {margin: 0}

#container {
  width: 1200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.items {
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 10px;
}

.item {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 1220px) {
  .items {padding: 0 10px}
}

@media (max-width: 990px) {
  .items {column-count: 2}
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .items {column-count: 1}
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <section class="items">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://www.nowphuket.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/layan-beach-550x400.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://www.globotreks.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Redding-Nature-600x450.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://liveinlosgatosblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Shannon-Valley-Ranch-open-space-trail-650x500.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://www.9corerealty.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Collier-County-4-700x550.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://webbox.imgix.net/images/aisrvqxbdirtzdby/c141a47e-bdd2-4687-a795-61141548c195.jpg?auto=enhance,compress&fit=crop&w=750&h=600" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://colonialbrickandstone.com/colonialwp/media/manitoulin-island-view-800x650.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://all-that-is-interesting.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/secret-gardens-kirstenbosch-2.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://www.thinkslovenia.com/upload/area_guides/south_top_10/kolpa.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://www.viaventure.com/wp-content/uploads/450x300-Lamanai03.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://webbox.imgix.net/images/aisrvqxbdirtzdby/c141a47e-bdd2-4687-a795-61141548c195.jpg?auto=enhance,compress&fit=crop&w=750&h=600" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://colonialbrickandstone.com/colonialwp/media/manitoulin-island-view-800x650.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://all-that-is-interesting.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/secret-gardens-kirstenbosch-2.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://www.thinkslovenia.com/upload/area_guides/south_top_10/kolpa.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://www.viaventure.com/wp-content/uploads/450x300-Lamanai03.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://www.fredericanaturereserve.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/500x350-px-F1-10.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://www.nowphuket.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/layan-beach-550x400.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://www.globotreks.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Redding-Nature-600x450.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://liveinlosgatosblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Shannon-Valley-Ranch-open-space-trail-650x500.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://www.9corerealty.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Collier-County-4-700x550.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```